# Nested MouseArea hover

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, archlinux, qt5.5

I'm having issues with nested `MouseArea`s.
When I click the red `Rectangle` it triggers the `exited` event on the top `Rectangle` (for me at least). Is this intended behavior? If so, is there a workaround?

Edit

Clarification
What I want is to be able to keep the hover for the top `Rectangle` while clicking the child `Rectangle` (the top `Rectangle` should stay `blue`). This is useful if I want to hide and unhide buttons etc. on hover, which is common practice in web interfaces (HTML/CSS). Doing this now causes weird effects as clicking the buttons that has been revealed by the `entered` signal will disappear when you click them.

Edit

I made a Javascript demonstration with the wanted behavior: 
https://jsfiddle.net/uo4vousu/
Even if you click the red rectangle the parent stays blue, which is what I want. In the QML example the parent becomes green.
I updated the QML code to mach the jsfiddle.

Edit

It might be a linux only problem.

Here's an example:

```qml
Rectangle {
    id: top
    width: 100
    height: 32
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    color: "green"

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        hoverEnabled: true
        onExited: top.color = "green"
        onEntered: top.color = "blue"

        Rectangle {
            id: child
            width: 16
            height: 16
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            color: "red"
            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent
                onPressed: child.color="gray"
                onReleased: child.color="red"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out that this issue is only present when using the Awesome window manager. I don't know what causes this, but I'm marking this as solved for now anyways.

Answer (score 1):

The easy way:

```
Rectangle {
    id: top
    width: 100
    height: 32
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    color: "green"
    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        hoverEnabled: true
        onExited: top.color = "green"
        onEntered: top.color = "blue"
        Rectangle {
            width: 16
            height: 16
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            color: "red"
            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent
                hoverEnabled: true
                onExited: top.color = "blue"
                onEntered: top.color = "green"
                onClicked: console.log("Clicked")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

you can use some math,

```
Rectangle {
    id: top
    width: 100
    height: 32
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    signal sgnEnteredZone()
    color: "green"
    onSgnEnteredZone:  {
        top.color = "blue"
    }
    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        hoverEnabled: true
        onMouseXChanged:{

            if( (mouseX <inRect.x ||mouseX>inRect.width + inRect.x )
                    && (mouseY <inRect.y ||mouseY>inRect.height + inRect.y)
                    )
                sgnEnteredZone()
            else
                top.color = "green"

        }
        onMouseYChanged:{
            if( (mouseX <inRect.x ||mouseX>inRect.width + inRect.x )
                    && (mouseY <inRect.y ||mouseY>inRect.height + inRect.y)
                    )
                sgnEnteredZone()
            else
                top.color = "green"
        }


        Rectangle {
            id:inRect
            width: 16
            height: 16
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            color: "red"
            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked: console.log("Clicked")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: None of the above really solved the problem, I apologize for not specifying what I really wanted to happen, I edited my question to clarify the issue.

Comment: I understand, I dont have this behavior, it's not logic that it sends the exit signal, I am using Qt 5.5.0 on windows

Comment: I see, thanks. Then this might be a linux issue as I'm using Arch linux. Will try this on windows later to confirm.